# Pandas how to check percentile of each element of a line at a corresponding column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a list:

```
l = [4,1,6,7]
```

and a dataframe `df`:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  4  1  0
2  7  5  0  9
```

And I want, for each element in the list, get the amount of numbers that are smaller than him in the column of its location in the dataframe.
So here, the output will be:

```
[1,0,3,2]
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Your variable df is not a DataFrame, is not even valid Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
df.lt(l).sum().to_list()
```

output:

```
[1, 0, 3, 2]
```

input dataframe:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  4  1  0
2  7  5  0  9
```

Comment: How can I add relative location? (to get [0.33,0,1,0.66])

Comment: do you mean `s = df.lt(l).sum() ; (s/s.max()).to_list()` or `df.lt(l).mean()`?